# Hiding Empty or Null Values Of the Retriving Table

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="(SELECT userID AS ID,userName FROM user) UNION ALL 
(SELECT pageID AS ID,pageName FROM page) ORDER BY ID ASC";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{   
    echo "<ul class='user'>";
    echo '<li>';
    echo $row['userName'];echo '</li>';
    echo '<li>';
    echo $row['pageName'];echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

this is my simple code i have join two tables by using union but the result is different then what i want  in the first iteraton userName is printed and pageName `<li>`is empty,in the second iteration the pageName is printed and userName `<li>` is empty  so what i dont want is that the empty values 
should not be consider in the query only printed result should be echo
and see in the given image every 2nd `<li>` has one empty value and i dont know how do i achieve it 
[image: image for the above query]

Comment: [try this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aed9a/2), what you need is a join.

Comment: no no i dont wana use join here because i dont want to join two tables records together

Comment: well.. *in the first iteraton userName is printed and pageName <li>is empty,in the second iteration the pageName is printed and userName <li> is empty* -- this is pretty obvious as you'll have a row with `userName` set but `pageName` empty because it's a row from user..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{    
echo "<ul class='user'>";
   if(isset($row['userName'])){
   echo '<li>';
   echo $row['userName'];echo '</li>'; 
   }
   if(isset($row['pageName'])){
   echo '<li>';
   echo $row['pageName'];
   echo '</li>'; 
   }
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: `$row['pageName']` is never set.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the [`UNION` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) states:

> The column names from the first `SELECT` statement are used as the column names for the results returned.

In consequence, the columns returned by your query are named `ID` and `userName`. There is no `pageName`. That's why `$row['pageName']` is always empty.

---

> i have join two tables by using union

[`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) doesn't [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). `UNION` puts together the result sets of two separate queries, `JOIN` allows you to generate rows in the result set that contain values from two or more tables.